# Is this scratch or just dirt?

Tags: dslr, sensor

The things I highlighted in the following photo, are they scratches on the sensor or just dirt?

[image]

Comment: Is this your full sensor or a cropped area?

Answer (score 1):

At such low resolution and such heavy compression it is hard to say. The lines could be streaks from cleaning fluid used to clean the sensor. Or they could be caused by scratches on the top of the cover plate.

The streaks to the far right look like cleaning fluid residue. It's harder to tell for the two you have circled.

Answer (score 0):

This is just dirt. Not likely that the cover glass over the image sensor is scratched. Check your camera manual for proper cleaning method.

Comment: I meant the lines, can you spot them?